# Why did Davy Jones' little white crabs help Jack escape from Davy Jones Locker?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

When the motley crew goes to rescue Cap'n Jack Sparrow from Davy Jones Locker in part 3 of the *Pirates of the Caribbean* film franchise, we find Jack on-board a desert-bound ship populated with his many selves. As the movie unfolds, thousands if not millions of small white crabs appear and assist with Jack's escape.

As far as I can remember, Davy Jones had *Aquaman*-like powers over sea creatures and owned a magic locker that he collected souls in.

Why did Davy Jones' little white crabs help Jack escape from Davy Jones Locker?

Comment: Because they are not devi jones crabs, they belongs to that black lady

Comment: And if you remember, that black lady was Calypso--the sea goddess.

Comment: +1, but is "Pirates" on-topic here?

Comment: @DVK - I would think it would fall into the 'fantasy' section of "sci-fi and fantasy" quite well, given that it delves into the underworld, spiritual forces, old curses, gods and the like

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It wasn't Davy Jones', but **Tia Dalma's** which, afterwards, is revealed to be *Calypso*.

This is set clear a couple of times during the movie. The first time, while still in the locker and they *find* Jack, the remaining crabs get under her skirt. Later in the film, when *Calypso* is released (the scene where she is tied to the ship's mast and starts *growing*) she scatters into these crabs.